# Best Practice ...Session Timeout in NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I just took on a new project (developed by another company), and I want to add a 30-minute inactive session timeout.   I found a simple script to use via VueJS, but I'm not sure what the best way to implement this is in NuxtJS.    Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Looks like they are just using the built-in Auth functionality in Nuxt.   I'm just not sure if I should add my logic as a component, middleware, plugin?

I've included the package and nuxt.config examples here - https://gist.github.com/TheJason/3701295fc28175436a8cad5bb05b4912

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/idle-vue which seems pretty straightforward, but doesn't account for the NuxtJS framework.

Comment: There is no built-in auth in Nuxt. Can you please show us some code or at least the `package,json`/`nuxt.config.js` here? If you need it globally, you could define it as a [client plugin only](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/plugins#object-syntax). At the end, Nuxt is basically Vue on steroids so it is totally compatible.

Comment: Ok...  yeah still trying to wrap my head around this...  Here's what I was referring to
https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth/

I just updated the question to include the package and nuxt.config

https://gist.github.com/TheJason/3701295fc28175436a8cad5bb05b4912

Comment: Alright, and what did you tried so far?

Comment: I just created a component with the idle-vue logic in it.    But couldn't really figure out how to load it.    I'm being overly cautious because I don't want to mess up what's currently in place.   I'm going to take a look at the client plug-in option you mention

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best to add it as a plugin; Here's how:

First create an 'idle-vue.js' file in the plugins directory;

```js
//plugins/idle-vue.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import IdleVue from 'idle-vue';

const eventsHub = new Vue();

Vue.use(IdleVue, {
    eventEmitter: eventsHub,
    idleTime: 60000
    startAtIdle: false
  });
```

Then add it in the plugins section of your nuxt config:

```js
//nuxt.config.js
plugins: [
    { src: "@/plugins/idle-vue", mode: 'client' },
    ...
]
```

Then in the component you wish to use the idle timer in, you can use the hooks as follows:

```js
async onIdle() {
    this.doSomethingWhenUserIsIdle();
}
async onActive() {
    this.doSomethingWhenUserIsNoLongerIdle();
}
```

Here's the related links:

[nuxt with idle-view](https://github.com/soixantecircuits/idle-vue/issues/46)

[using with Nuxt 2.4<](https://github.com/soixantecircuits/idle-vue/issues/39)

Comment: If it's not needed, there is no point into importing it globally. Local import is totally fine.